# PHP Mail: How to send email in base64 format and attachments together?

Tags: php

I have a form that is filled out and is generated in HTML format, but sometimes this form is very large, so I need to convert it to base64 and then send it through PHP Mail. However, the same email does not work when I need to send an attachment together. It seems to me that it is possible through some kind of Multipart, but I can't quite understand how it works.

Comment: Hi Diodo, welcome to Stack Overflow! This forum is specifically targeted to help with concrete problems, which are backed up by a reproducible example. Can you provide us with some code to help us solve your problem? See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do yourself a really big favour and use a library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for this instead, if you can. Trying to put together multipart emails by hand, with 500 different kinds of inner and outer boundaries, will slowly drive you insane.